# Can a database serve two different installations on localhost?

Tags: upgrading

I have a Drupal 6 live site backed up to my localhost and I want to transition the localhost version to 7 before uploading to become the live site.

In my mind the ideal process would be to have a separate 7 install accessing the same (or mirrored) database so I still have a clean 6 backup in case of trouble with the live site. Does anyone have an opinion if this possible and/or the best way to do it?

I have MAMP Pro driving the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using a single database to serve multiple applications (including multiple Drupal instances).  However, they need to be completely separate instances. You cannot use a Drupal 6 database instance as part of a Drupal 7 instance.  You must set up a clean Drupal 7 instance, and then migrate the content from a Drupal 6 instance into it, using the [standard procedures](https://drupal.org/node/570162) for upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

To do this, you use something known as "table prefix".  When you install Drupal (both 6 and 7) on the database setup page you get during installation, you can expand a tab to get to *Advanced options*.  This gives you access to some extra options, including "table prefix".

The "table prefix" allow for multiple instances sharing the database.  For instance, if your existing Drupal 6 site is set up *without* a table prefix, you can use the table prefix `d7_` to set up a Drupal 7 configuration in the *same* database that will not interfere with your Drupal 6 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal codebase is always strongly connected with same version of database. You can not use Drupal 6 version of codebase with Drupal 7 version of database and viceversa... Because schema differs from D6 to D7 versions..

From your question .. I understand that you are trying to upgrade your Drupal 6 version to Drupal 7 version.

For Drupal core upgrade you can follow this [Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/570162) in D.O

For Upgrading Contributed Modules from D6 to D7 version [Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/948216)

There is also a "[Coder project](http://drupal.org/project/coder) that can help automate the process of converting your custom modules from D6 to D7.

As you mentioned, It's always good to have backups. Make sure you have a backup before upgrading your Drupal Website.

Comment: Thanks Anil, I am now rethinking if my idea is asking for trouble. My thought was the upgrade will be over a long timeframe while I develop a new theme so dual database would be best. I think I will upgrade (with backups)and work on new theme on localhost. Thanks